# Scala method chaining - hello world

Tags: python, scala, fluent, chaining

I'm currently learning method chaining. I've provided a working python example.

```
#!/bin/python3
import sys

class Generator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def echo(self, myStr):
        sys.stdout.write(myStr)
        return self

g = Generator()
g.echo("Hello, ").echo("World!\n")
```

But the Scala version doesn't seem to work, no text is being output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala

final class Printer() {
  def echo(msg: String): this.type = {
    println(msg)
    this
  }
}

class Driver {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var pr = new Printer();
    pr.echo("Hello, ").echo("World!")
  }
}
```

Does anybody know why the scala version is not working and why?

Comment: Code is fine, works for me, must be the way you run it.

Comment: You need to compile the file first using scalac and run the compiled .class file then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile and call your scala bytecode aferwards. Also, you don't need to specify `this.type` if your `Printer` is `final`, e.g. if your `driver.scala` file contains:

```
final class Printer() {
  def echo(msg: String) = {
    println(msg)
    this
  }
}

object Driver {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var pr = new Printer();
        pr.echo("Hello, ").echo("World!")
   }
}
```

Then just call:

```
scalac driver.scala
scala Driver
```

Comment: Thanks, changing class to object, and compiling then executing fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the main method in your script.

`new Driver().main(...)` should solve your problem.

Besides, it is the norm to define a main method in an object.

So, instead of

```
class Driver {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var pr = new Printer();
    pr.echo("Hello, ").echo("World!")
  }
}

new Driver().main(...)
```

I would recommend the following.

```
object Driver {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var pr = new Printer();
    pr.echo("Hello, ").echo("World!")
  }
}

Driver.main(...)
```

Good luck!